# Django Alter existing table without programaticly

Tags: django

When my Django project is installed, the db is created and my fixtures are used to populate the db, this normal work flow works great. However at a specific time (after the db and its content are created) I want to alter an existing record in the db.

Is there a way to programmatically alter a record in an existing database table? Perhaps using python manage.py sqlall? If possible I want to avoid a 'hackish' solution like writing a little script that will run a sql alter command.

Comment: You can do this with south data migration.http://odolshinu.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/database-migration-in-django-using-south/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a python script, import your Django models and do the changes just like within a Django application. Then execute that script on the given time.